# Postman Script to set Environment variable

Tags: postman

I am creating a postman collection for one of API integration with our Service. Here we are using OAuth1.0 for authentication. I want to set the oauth init response **oauth_token**, **oauth_token_secret** into postman environment variables so that I can access them in further requests.
The response is in below format not a JSON.
**oauth_token=*oauth_token_value*&oauth_token_secret=*oauth_token_secret_value*&oauth_callback_confirmed=true**

I tried below script:

```
var output = require('querystring').parse(Response.text);
postman.setGlobalVariable("oauth_token", output.oauth_token);
postman.setGlobalVariable("oauth_token_secret", output.oauth_token_secret);
```

Can some one help me to set tokens into postman environment variables please.

Note: I am using chrome plugin Version 5.5.4, not native app.

Comment: Use native app.

Answer (score 1):

In the chrome extension you need to use `postman.setEnvironmentVariable()`:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("oauth_token", output.oauth_token);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("oauth_token_secret", output.oauth_token_secret);
```

For that you need to have an environment created and selected (no need to add any variable manually). How to do that is described here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/managing-environments/#creating-environments

Answer (score 0):

In the version of Postman I'm using, v10.11.2, there's no need for a Chrome extension. You can get and set variables with different scopes like this:

For Environment scope:
`pm.environment.set("key", "value"); pm.environment.get("key");`

For Global scope:
`pm.globals.set("key","value"); pm.globals.get("key");`

For Collection scope:
`pm.collectionVariables.set("key", "value"); pm.collectionVariables.get("key");`

For Local/Temporary scope:
`pm.variables.set("key","value"); pm.variables.get("key");`